# How to replace multiple parameters of a URL with regex php

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I have a logical problem, since I do not handle regular expressions very much. I would like to know how I can replace several values ​​from one URL to another value. For example:

http://example.com/values?value1=12121&order=3&external=AFB3432

I would like a regular expression to select the parameters and replace them with what I want:

http://example.com/values?value1=10000&order=3&external=AAAAA

If there is any better way than doing it with Regex, it would be great!

```
"params_": {
            "value1": {
                "paramName": "value1",
                "paramValue": "12121"
            },
            "order": {
                "paramName": "order",
                "paramValue": "3",

            },
            "external": {
                "paramName": "external",
                "paramValue": "AFB3432"
            },
```

Then, originally URL is:

http://example.com/values?value1=12121&order=3&external=AFB3432

But, i need change the values of "value1" and "external". The params never changes:

http://example.com/values?value1=10000&order=3&external=AAAAA

Thank you!

Comment: use this `(?<==).*?(?=&)|(?<==).*$`

Comment: How are you specifying the parameters you want to replace and their new values?

Comment: For example, in my script I receive a JSON and the logic that I have, I take out two parameters of the URL that must be replaced by the values ​​that I require. In this case, for the example, "value1" and "external" must be replaced. I only want to replace the values ​​of the parameters that I require (not all)

Comment: Could you give an example of how that works? It would be helpful in terms of giving an answer.

Comment: I edited it and put more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built-in PHP URL parsing ([`parse_url`](http://%60parse_url%60), [`parse_str`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)) and query building ([`http_build_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)) functions for this purpose. I'm assuming you can get the replacement values into an array:

```
$replacements = array('value1' => 10000, 'external' => 'AAAAA');
$url = 'http://example.com/values?value1=12121&order=3&external=AFB3432';
// extract the query part
$query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
// and parse it into variables
parse_str($query, $params);
// merge the parameter values with the replacements
$new_params = array_merge($params, $replacements);
// create a new query string
$new_query = http_build_query($new_params);
// and reassemble the URL
$new_url = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME) . "://" . parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST) . parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH) . "?" . $new_query;
echo $new_url;
```

Output:

```
http://example.com/values?value1=10000&order=3&external=AAAAA
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/vguDV)

Comment: Works! Now I can adapt it to my code. Thank you Nick!

Comment: @hupsisafyi what code? I can't see any code posted by you.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a more basic method of strpos and str_replace.

```
$link = "http://example.com/values?value1=12121&order=3&external=AFB3432*";

$find = ["value1=", "order=", "external="];
$repl = [10000, 3, "AAAAA"];

foreach($find as $key => $f){
    $pos1 = strpos($link, $f);
    $pos2 = strpos(substr($link, $pos1), "&");
// I substring $link above to make $pos2 a "lenght" instead of a position

    if($pos2 !== false){ // if $pos2 is false then it's the last argument
        $link = str_replace(substr($link, $pos1, $pos2), $f . $repl[$key], $link);
    }else{
        $link = str_replace(substr($link, $pos1), $f . $repl[$key], $link);
    }
}

echo $link;
```

https://3v4l.org/1VZiq

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this as per the examples you provide this will do the job**

```
(?<==).*?(?=&)|(?<==).*$
```

- `(?<==)` - Positive look behind. matches `=`.
- `.*?` - Matches anything except new line.
- `(?=&)` - Matches `&`.
- `|` - Alternation same as logical OR.
- `(?<==)` - Positive look behind. matches `=`.
- `.*$` - Matches any thing except newline up to end of string.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VPjXR4/2/)

Comment: It works but I am also selecting the order and that parameter I do not want to replace it. If you notice, I want to replace "value1" and "external". What I really want is to replace the values ​​of the parameters that I send to the Regex, because it can be a very long URL with many parameters

Comment: @well in case of dynamic parameters i think a parsing library will be more handy to use.

Comment: What I want is to replace the value of the parameters that I indicate. For example, "value1" I want to be worth 1000 and "external" worth AAAAA. The name of the parameter never changes

Comment: That's what I need but I see a problem. The order is being excluded, right? and in case I have more parameters, I would have to put them in the regular expression for the exclusion

Comment: @hupsisafyi that's what i said in case you have dynamic parameters to be included it's better to use a library.

Comment: They are not dynamic parameters, that is, in my code I receive a URL and depending on it, I modify the values ​​that I require. What I imagined was that in the regular expression I would look for the value of the objective parameter and modify it instead of excluding the ones I'm not going to modify

Comment: Thanks Code Maniac! I already managed to solve it. Excuse me for not explaining myself, my mistake